# Optimization of doing nothing functor

Tags: c++11, functor

Can I be sure that complier optimize doing nothing functor?

```
template< typename T = vector<short> >
struct WithoutTransform
{
    T operator()(const T &data)
    {
        return data;
    }
};
```

I use functors for

```
template<class Transformer>
void someFunction(Transformer tr)
{
    vector<short> data;
    ...
    anotherFunction(tr(data));

}
void anotherFunction(const vector<short> & data){...};

someFunction(WithoutTransform<>());
```

Comment: Why don't you try it? Build with different optimization levels, and examine the generated machine code as assembly.

Comment: I will try, but it is only for my compiler. Maybe there is better implementation?

Comment: Well your functor literaly says: make me a copy of `data`. Consider `const T &operator()(const T &data) { return data; }` in your tests.

Comment: compiler requires full information to provide optimizations. Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/g/fqKwqK) example: compiler can optimize no-op lambda, but cannot optimize no-op `std::function` because (due to type erasure) it doesn't know that `f` is actually a no-op `std::function`.